# Separating foreground objects from a background of the same color

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to perform segmentation of hand gestures where my background is also skin-colored.I have attached a sample image of the dataset. So far I have tried thresholding and canny edge detection but since both the foreground and the background are of the same color, these methods are not effective. Is there any other way to do this using python-opencv?

[image]

Comment: I had problem seeing the hand in front, as a human I needed to use my knowledge that hands have 5 fingers, and their relative positions, so there are 2 hands not just one, your task would be hard to do with image processing, you need machine learning, specifically instance segmentation, or  so my humble knowledge would suggest.

Comment: I see. Actually, I have three classes in this dataset ( 1 finger, 2 fingers and 3 fingers). I want to classify only the number of fingers. And, the position of the hand showing the fingers changes slightly in each image. Do you think such a problem comes under object detection?

Comment: If the position of the hand is about the same in all images, you can crop it, this should reduce the confusion with the other hand, CNN should be smart enough to correlate the result with the hand in front and ignore the hand in the back, given large enough dataset of course.

Comment: I have thousands of images. I don't think cropping will be a feasible option.

Comment: I believe if you input the images as is to a CNN you should get good results, CNN is made to do its own feature extraction and image enhancement, so there is no need to think about what filters to use, CNN will do it for you.